# How to send a dial string from the computer to asterisks to call a phone?

Tags: java, sip, asterisk, telephony, dialing

I've been trying to figure out how to send a dial string to the asterisks server which should then handle a call to the phone with that extension. I know there are programs like X-Lite and such but I don't want to manually dial it. I want to pass a string instead. Is there any way? Any help or tip would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can use AGI scripts to do this. From AGI scripts you can manage your asterisk box from any language you want

Answer (score 2):

I use `call files`. Just read: [Asterisk auto-dial out](http://www.voip-info.org/tiki-index.php?page=Asterisk+auto-dial+out).

I made simple CGI script that called via web server creates call file (remember to use temp directory) and then moves it to `/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing` and Asterisk do rest of work.

Answer (score 2):

Call files can help you easily but AGI using php or perl is far more better